# Gathering user input and put in formatted mail/attachment

Tags: android

I have a simple app which is gathering user input. Once the user enters what is requested (it is only text), he presses a confirm button and then I want this info to be send in the background via E-Mail. I do this in the form of a simple text - nothing fancy.

Now I want to understand is there a way to format the input data?
How can I put the information in a table so it is received in a table to my E-Mail? Or is there a way to put it on pdf/word and E-Mail it - all this in the background?

Comment: what do you mean in a table? a database table?

Comment: You could say that - a table with rows and columns and the input will be in the cells. All of this should be done on the devices, since I use the GMailSender

Comment: What happens if the user does not use Gmail? What happens when spammers find your account credentials in your app and start using it to send spam?

Comment: Would Firebase do the trick, based on your comment before the edit?

Comment: you can use firebase to store the information in a database, yes. but commonsware brought up a very valid point. you need security.

Comment: I guess I just didn't do my homework properly ... I thought GMailSender is actually I build-in API and it just uses the existing account. I saw now that it actually requires the complete set of information to send E-Mails. I guess I need to understand now whether Firebase can do the work after the information is received.